# Sistema de permissão

Tags: php, mysql, permissões

Tenho um sistema com login obrigatório.

O que deveria acontecer: Se a coluna "ativo" for = 1 redireciona pra determinada página, se for = 0 redireciona pra outra.

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST) AND (empty($_POST['id']) OR empty($_POST['senha']) AND (`ativo` = 1)) {
  header("Location: principal.php"); exit;
} else {
    if (!empty($_POST) AND (empty($_POST['id']) OR empty($_POST['senha']) AND (`ativo` = 0){
        header("Location: principalUSU.php"); exit;
}
}
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'db_formacao') or trigger_error(mysql_error());
$identifiant = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
$senha = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['senha']);
$ativo = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ativo']);

$sql = "SELECT `id`, `id`, `senha`, `ativo`  FROM `usuarios` WHERE (`id` = '". $id ."') AND (`senha` = '". $senha ."') AND (`ativo` = '". $ativo ."')";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($query) != 1) {
  echo "Login inválido!"; exit;
} else {
  $resultado = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
}
```

Só que em ambas as ocasiões redireciona pra página `principal.php`.

Comment: Acredito que há algum erro nas verificação de `$_POST`. Pra resolver isso eu tentaria dar um `print_r($_POST)` depois que for submetido o formulário pra ver o que estou recebendo nesse array e tentar achar o erro.

Comment: Você tá verificando se uma string qualquer é um. Acho que o certo seria `_POST['ativo'] == 1`

Comment: Tentei assim, mas ainda redireciona direto pra principal.php

Answer (score 1):

Eu sugiro trocar os operadores `AND` e `OR` por `&&` e `||`, respectivamente. O motivo é a prioridade na execução de operadores. Isso pode ser confuso em algumas linguagens, mas em PHP esse assunto é especialmente traiçoeiro. Veja por conta própria executando os seguintes trechos:

```
<?php
$foo = true && false;
var_dump($foo);

$bar = true AND false;
var_dump(bar);
?>
```

`$foo` será falso, como se espera em qualquer linguagem, mas `$bar` será verdadeiro. O único motivo que posso imaginar para justificar isso é que os autores do PHP usam drogas diferentes das que os outros designers de linguagens usam.

Então, no seu caso, acho que o `if` para logo depois de ver se o POST está vazio ou não. A troca de operadores deve resolver.

Comment: Ah, entendi, foi bom saber disso! Fiz as alterações mas ainda a mesma coisa. :/

Answer (score 0):

Tenta assim ó:

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_POST) AND (empty($_POST['id']) OR empty($_POST['senha']) {
        if (`ativo` === 1)) {
            header("Location: principal.php");
            exit;
            // Praque esse "exit" aqui, fiquei sem compreender;
        if (`ativo` === 0) {
            header("Location: principalUSU.php"); 
            exit;
            // fiquei boiando
         }
    }
    // ...
?>
```

[EDIT 1]:

```
<?php
    $locat = "";
    if (!empty($_POST) AND (empty($_POST['id']) OR empty($_POST['senha']) {
        if (`ativo` === 1)) {
            $locat = "Location: principal.php";
            // exit;
            // comentei essa linha pois não sei pra que serve;
        if (`ativo` === 0) {
            $local = "Location: principalUSU.php"; 
            // exit;
            // o mesmo do comentario anterior
         }
         header($locat);
    }
    // ...
?>
```

como no comentario ainda continua direcionando para o primeiro caso: coluna `'ativo' === 1`, voce precisa dar um print do valor disso para saber se esta sendo passado corretamente

Comment: Então, também redireciona pra principal.php

Comment: @MarianaFerreira Eu sugiro dar um print no valor de cada variável que você verifica nos if's. Assim você poderá identificar com mais facilidade o que provoca o problema.

Comment: Então, quando eu tento abrir a página responsável pela validação do login, aparece que ela não está funcionando. Porém, consigo logar normalmente. e não logar se eu estiver digitando um login inválido.